# What is meant by "a series of deltas"?

Tags: synchronization, backend, trello, delta

I was going through a [blog post](https://tech.trello.com/syncing-changes/) by Dan Lew at Trello where he mentioned using a "series of deltas" to store changes made offline.

Can anyone explain me what is a "delta" basically. Any reference would help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the basic definition of a "Delta" by reading the [tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delta) for delta in Stack Overflow.

Its defined as: -

> A Delta is a file which represents the changes between two or more revisions of structured or semi-structured data

So as far as my understanding, it is a file used to track the changes made to a piece of data.

For example: -

If client A changes a file with contents X to X1.

Then the delta for this operation will be something like

```
X -> X1 (Client A)
```

Please do correct me if I'm wrong.